# C++ how to return inner class

Tags: c++

I have a small problem with my class design. I have two classes - Application and Window. Application owns one Window. Now I have two ways how to write it.

1) Add Window to private scope of Application
In this case I have to add method getWindow() which would return the Window object to user to allow to manipulate with it (call its methods).

```
Application app;
app.getWindow().setTitle( "..." );
```

2) Add Window to public scope of Application
And access the Window like:

```
Application app;
app.window.setTitle( "..." );
```

In case of simple language type (bool, int, ...) I would choose the first method without asking...

Which of these two ways would be better to use? Thank you for advices.

Comment: Both are equally valid, depending on a number of factors; however it really boils down to personal preference and project specification: sometimes all instance calls are mandated via accessors and mutators, others it can be mandatory to expose encapsulated classes directly. Efficiency sometimes plays a role: if you can afford the extra function call at execution time or not may be the ultimate deciding factor.

Comment: There is no good, bad or ugly getter/setter - pick one!

Comment: @DieterLücking Note that `window` isn't a getter method ...

Comment: @GMasucci The extra function call for a getter is almost always optimized out by the compiler in the release version. Therefore, execution time is no argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the first one is the only good way.

Be careful though to return a Window reference and not a Window object. If you return an object a copy of the object will be constructed and you no longer manipulate the original object.

The reason why I would prefer only the first way (and usually why in textbooks you find "do not access data members from extern"): Before returning the value (in this case the object reference) you can manipulate it as you want. For example you need to implement your own window class. If you return it with a getter function you still can cast it to the original window class thus the rest of the code (that only needs the setTitle, etc...) will be unchanged.

==> Only the application class needs to know how its data members are organized, noone else.

Answer (score 2):

The first option is more sophisticated:

```
Window& Application::getWindow() {
   // check for NULL dereference of App object:
   ASSERT(this != NULL);

   // add trace:
   TRACE(__FUNCTION__ " was called!");

   // other debug/probing code
#ifdef DEBUG
   static int count = 0;
   ++count
#endif
   return window;
}
```

Comment: Would not this cause a compiler error? Application::window is a const member and you try to return it as non const...

Comment: Your class declaration is not shown. You can return a const reference from the function.

Comment: Of course, but if I return a const reference I would not be able to call non-const methods. BTW: Is not every member instance of class set to const by default?

Comment: So make the window data member non-const. Makes no sense to have a const object you can't use...